# How can I evaluate the time when the system get close to stable point without fully calculate the whole system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system $\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=f\left(x,y\right) \\
\frac{dy}{dt}=g\left(x,y\right) \\
\end{cases}$ ,with IC: $\begin{cases}
x\left(t_0\right)=x_0 \\
y\left(t_0\right)=y_0 \\
\end{cases}$.

There is a stable point $\left(x^{\ast},y^{\ast}\right)$  makes the system satisfies 
$\begin{cases}
f\left(x^{\ast},y^{\ast}\right)=0 \\
g\left(x^{\ast},y^{\ast}\right)=0 \\
\end{cases}$.
And $f, g$ depend on $x,y$ are very complicated nonlinear functions without analytical expressions.

I can use numerical algoritms such as Runge-Kutta to solve the whole system,but it will call $f,g$ hundreds of times,which is very slow.

My question is , how can I evaluate the time $t$ when $\left(x,y\right)$ get close to stable point $\left(x^{\ast},y^{\ast}\right)$ without fully calculate the whole system. 'Close' means, for example,$\left|x_{i+1}-x_i\right|<10^{-3}$ .The algoritms should call $f,g$ as few as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing something about $f,g$, it is impossible to say.

Comment: They are just functions without analytical expressions.I can get values for each pair of $\left(x,y\right)$ , just very slow. What else do you want to know about $f,g$ ?

Comment: Unless you know something about $f,g$, there is no way of even guessing. Do you know the basin of attraction for the stable point? Perhaps I misunderstand what it is that you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for my math. I will do some investigation on what is basin of attraction,and how to calculate this area.By far,I know nothing about $f,g$ expect their values.But I don't want to do something like large scale scanning because it't very slow.

Comment: Assuming $x,y$ is the position of a particle, I just want to know how long it will take from the beginning point to somewhere close to the stable point. Close,not reach,because it will be infinity of time. Thank you very much for you have already told me.

Comment: Hi, I think there is no way of knowing in general, unless you know something more about your system. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will try to find some other way to solve this problem. And get more detail on my system.Thanks!